# Google Drive API File Insert Docx

Tags: google-drive-api, docx

I am using the Google Drive API to upload files. It is working when I upload Doc or Docx file. However, I am not able to open uploaded Docx file in the Google Drive Interface.

Here is my call

```
$result = $service->files->insert(
    $file,
        array(
            'data'       => $data,
            'mimeType'   => 'application/octet-stream',
            'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            'convert'    => true
        )
    );
```

no matter I set the convert true or false. I found the docx file can not be converted. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

After uploading the file to Google Drive, you to goto `Settings` and select the checkbox that says: `Convert the uploaded files to Google Docs editor format`. This is allowing me to edit the docx file.

Check this page for more information: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/0l3HJhqhNGs

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I found that mimeType for Docx should be "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document". And it will convert the file to google doc format automatically.